# JQuery, add "." in front of generated range of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code so far:

```
var low = parseInt(jQuery('#min-value-span').text());
var high = parseInt(jQuery('#max-value-span').text());
var dynamicrange = [];
while(low<=high){
    dynamicrange.push(low++)
}


 jQuery('#protein_range_button').attr('data-testing', dynamicrange);
```

What this does is grabs the values from `#min-value-span` and `#max-value-span` and creates every number from the low to the high. Then I add those values to a data-attribute called `data-testing`.

Ex. if min is 0 and max is 20, then the div looks like this:

```
<div id="protein_range_button" class="filter" data-testing="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20">Filter</div>
```

This is where I want the change, but not sure how. I want it to add a "." in front of every number. like this:

```
<div id="protein_range_button" class="filter" data-testing=".0,.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9,.10,.11,.12,.13,.14,.15,.16,.17,.18,.19,.20">Filter</div>
```

How can I do this? Can you supply the code :)
Thanks!

Comment: Loop the array, add a dot? Try `.push('.'+ low++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your loop to this:

```
while(low<=high){
    dynamicrange.push('.'+low++)
}
```

Comment: Yes,Yes,Yes!! Thanks! It's the simple things that make me happy. I'll accept answer as soon as it lets me